# How to ssh into ubuntu (set up in virtualbox) while turned off

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, putty

I was wondering if it was possible to ssh into my ubuntu which is set up in oracle vm, while it is turned off. I am able to ssh into my ubuntu via putty when it is running, but when I turn it off I am not able to do so.

What are the necessary steps to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to switch it on.

It's unlikely you're going to have Wake On LAN available for a virtual host, because a switched off VM is more like having the power cord removed. A switched off physical host isn't really switched off - it's more in a semi-off state that AFAIK is not emulated within VirtualBox (or any other VM environment).